# Can Server-side js (nodejs) omit the ` sign?

Tags: node.js

I found a code segment like this works perfect on my sever:

```
const Button = (props) => {
  const { className, disabled, onClick, children, ...rest } = props
  return (
    <button type="button"
            className={classNames('btn', className, disabled && 'disabled')}
            disabled={disabled}
            onClick={(e) => !disabled && onClick(e) }
            {...rest}>
      {children}
    </button>
  )
}
```

It's a nodejs script. I thought it should be something like:

```
const Button = (props) => {
  const { className, disabled, onClick, children, ...rest } = props
  return (
    `<button type="button"
            className={classNames('btn', className, disabled && 'disabled')}
            disabled={disabled}
            onClick={(e) => !disabled && onClick(e) }
            {...rest}>
      {children}
    </button>`
  )
}
```

So on server-side, I can omit the `` ` `` sign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot omit the ` sign on server side.

The first snippet you showed are not HTML. They are JSX syntax. The server code is being transpiled either by TypeScript or Babel or similar transpiler.

If it is transpiled by TypeScript, the code will have a `tsconfig.json` that enabled [JSX transpilation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#jsx).

If it is transpiled by Babel, the babel config would have included JSX plugins like [this one](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx) or similar, somewhere in the config plugin tree.

Even if you are not using any transpiler, adding ` sign to the code will not yield valid syntax because that is not a valid HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the filename is `.js`, so `JSX` can also have the `js` extension?

Comment: @AGamePlayer yes, if the transpiler plugin supports it. From what I know, Babel plugins support it.